# How to pass componentDidMount function to deep layer children in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-boilerplate

I have question about passing componentDidMount function from parent to deep laying child. 
I have a list of items, which are selected by items status. After I change one of the item's status, I need to re-render parent to get new data. Tricky part for me is that, that I can't find way, how to pass componentDidMount function or action to fetch my list's data again.

My parent class:

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onCompMount();
  }

  render() {
    const { error, loading, list } = this.props;

    const pageListProps = {
      loading,
      error,
      list,
    };

    return (
      <article>
        <div>
          <PageList {...pageListProps} />
        </div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

My 1st child:

```
function PageList({ loading, error, list }) {
  if (loading) {
    return <List component={LoadingIndicator} />;
  }

  if (error !== false) {
    const ErrorComponent = () => (
      <ListItem item="Something went wrong, please try again!" />
    );
    return <List component={ErrorComponent} />;
  }

  if (list !== false) {
    return <List items={list} component={PageItem} />;
  }
  return null;
}
```

2nd child:

```
export class PageItem extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false,
    };

    this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { item } = this.props;

    // Put together the content of the repository
    const content = (
      <Wrapper>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <button onClick={this.openModal}>Decline</button>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Preview"
        >
          <Form close={this.closeModal} />
        </Modal>
      </Wrapper>
    );
```

And my last child where I want after submit to re-render parent container:

```
export class Form extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <form
          onSubmit={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.submit();
            this.props.close();
            //Somehow re-render parent
          }}
        >
          <div className="row" style={{ textAlign: 'start' }}>
            Do you really want to change status?
            <div className="col-md-12 buttonContainer">
              <ButtonA
                label="Submit"
                style={{ width: '50%' }}
                primary
                type="submit"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

What I have tried is to reload page with `window.location.reload();` and it works. But I think it is bad practice with React. Maybe someone could advise me how to make it better?

EDIT: I am adding parent reducer and 4th child reducer.

Parent reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  loading: false,
  error: false,
  listData: {
    list: false,
  },
});

function pageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LIST_BEGIN:
      return state
        .set('loading', true)
        .set('error', false)
        .setIn(['listData', 'list'], false);
    case FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS:
      return state
        .setIn(['listData', 'list'], action.list)
        .set('loading', false);
    case FETCH_LIST_FAILURE:
      return state.set('error', action.error).set('loading', false);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default pageReducer;
```

4th child reducer:

```
const initialState = fromJS({});

function formReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUBMIT:
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default formReducer;
```

Comment: You make use of redux for the fetch ?

Comment: In which child you're updating items status ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, last child has redux-saga POST method, where I send update status (list object) to backend.

Comment: You must fetch data in parent componenDidMount

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, maybe you could explain about what data you are talking? I am fetching data in componentDidMount. But I need to refecth after I make update to database.

Comment: Can you please explain what  you want to achieve after post request

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, I want to re-render parent container. So my items list would be re-fetched. Right now, after post I am trying to route into same page, where I am with `history.push(location)` , but it's not re-rendering parent component.

Comment: You want to see updated list after posting data?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, yes, exactly :)

Comment: where is your method `submit()` ?

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, it is submit action. `export function submit() {
  return {
    type: SUBMIT,
  };
}`

Comment: You can dispatch action from parent and connect reducer with 4th lvl child.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, maybe you could show me an example how to connect reducer with few containers?

Comment: you have to show your action reducer also. So i would be able to do it

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, I have added parent and 4th child reducer.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor, I did it myself. Big thanks you to for offering this solution. If you want post your answer and I will accept it. Thank you again.

Comment: sure. I'm glad it helped you and do upvote too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `Redux` or React's new `Context API` to avoid prop drilling issue in react. 
In your use you can dispatch action from parent component and connect relevant reducer to your 4th level child. So when your reducer updates global state (store), your connected component will re-render and take updated state as in props.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `this.props.onCompMount()` as props to child components and then call it in child component every time it gets updated.

Comment: Yes I would do this, if I need to pass function from parent to child. Now I need to pass function to 4th lvl child.

Comment: You can pass it as props from 1st lvl to 2nd lvl child, then from 2nd to 3rd and then from 4th to 3rd.

Comment: maybe you could show me how to do it using my code? I couldn't make that work.